# How to parameterise a part of a string in an sql command inside a python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parameter-passing

I have an sql query :

```
cur.execute("copy tmp from 's3://orders/20200515/orders.csv")
```

How can i parameterize the /20200515/ part of the query ?

Somthing like :

```
list1=['20200515','20200516','20200517']
for A in list1:
   cur.execute("copy tmp from 's3://orders/A/orders.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `str.format`:

```
list1 = ['20200515','20200516','20200517']
for A in list1:
   cur.execute("copy tmp from 's3://orders/{}/orders.csv".format(A))
```

See the [**official documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.6, you can use f-strings. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

```
list1 = ['20200515','20200516','20200517']
for A in list1:
   cur.execute(f"copy tmp from 's3://orders/{A}/orders.csv")
```

F-strings are more efficient than other string formatting mechanisms